# How to stop Grand Totals from being considered for the shape sizing, for both rows and columns in Tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have the below data structure in a worksheet and once I add Grand Totals to my Rows and Columns, the sizes of the Grand Total shapes force all the shapes in the inside of the table to become really small.

Is there a way to **exclude the Grand Totals from being considered for the shape sizing** and maybe just let them come up as text?

[image]

Comment: Why include grand totals at all if the table is a graphic display of magnitude?

Comment: Because users might want to know the total of a given dimension, without having to do any mental comparisons of mark sizes?
@matt_black

Comment: I'd argue this is a problem in the dataviz design, not in Tableau. You can either have a *table* with correct totals or a *dataviz* with a correct scale but not both at the same time. Though you might be able to fiddle the size scale to cap it so the rest of the table works but the grand totals are *visually* wrong. Or, use a separate table and viz.